# hibernate createalias add "Or" condition to inner join

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria, alias, conditional-statements

I would like to do using hibernate criteria and createAlias a query like this:

SELECT
  `table1`."any_field"
FROM
  `table1` inner join `table2` on `table1`.`field1` = `table2`.`field1` OR `table1`.`field2` = table2.field1

where .....

The main problem is I'm not able to add "OR" condition to the inner join, all restrictions and stuff I apply always becomes "AND".

Comment: criteria can only walk mapped associations andcan not build arbitrary sql in the from clause. Hql is a better fit for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

certanly not efficient:

```
session.createCriteria(T2.class, "t2")
    .add(Restriction.or(
        Subquery.exists(DetachedCriteria.for(T1.class).add(Restrictions.eqProperty("field1", "t2.field1")),
        Subquery.exists(DetachedCriteria.for(T1.class).add(Restrictions.eqProperty("field2", "t2.field1")))
    .list();
```